# Vuex | Можно ли импортировать vue router во vuex хранилище?

Tags: vue.js, vuex, vue-router

Если я импортирую vue router во vuex хранилище для того что-бы к примеру в нём получать параметры из адресной строки то какие проблемы это может создать? Станет ли это влиять на производительность?
Вот мой главный vue компонент app.js

```js
import './bootstrap';
import { createApp } from 'vue';
import store from './vuex';
import router from './router';
import Index from './components/Index.vue';
import './axios';

const app = createApp({
    el: '#app',

    components: {
        Index
    }
});

app.use(router);
app.use(store);
app.mount('#app');
```

Я хочу для файла ./vuex.js в начало импортировать файл ./router.